# change form content to thank you message

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

So I've been looking around a lot of different ways to get a thank you message when answering a form, and realised that there are plenty of ways.

However, I just want to change the content in a div box (where the form is) to a thank you message after one has clicked the submit button, and submitted the form, without refreshing the page or redirecting to another. 
In other words, the form disappears, and a Thank You message appears instead. How do I do this?

I want it to look like on the [HeforShe website](http://www.heforshe.org).

Comment: post you code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the value after the form is submitted.
You can use the **onsubmit** event to hook up in the form submission.

```html
<form onsubmit="sayThanks()">
```

```js
function sayThanks() {
  document.getElementById("thankYouMessageDiv").innerHTML = "Your message";
}
```